# How can I turn off push notifications of other apps when Im using my app

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I created an app which receives push notifications from my server. At the same time, if some other app is sending push notifications (for e.g., whatsaap, twitter), the notification is getting displayed when I'm using my app. I want to hide all other app's push notifications except my app's push notifications. Can this be done in iOS? I want my app to receive push notifications only from my server but not from the other apps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, only the user can control which notifications are displayed.

Comment: do you mean I can hide other app's notifications?@Paulw11

Comment: Go to settings of your iOS device and switch of the push notifications you are not interested in.

Comment: if you follow @dasdom then you never get push notification until you again enabled it in settings...

Comment: Sorry i don't want to disable push notifications manually, i just want to hide all other push notifications when the user is using my app (through coding if possible) and let the user to see notifications when he closes my app.

Comment: No, as @dasdom said, I meant that the user is in control of *their* device and only they can decide which notifications are received

Comment: @iosdevelpr I'm very glad that this is not possible. Each an every App would do this and iOS would be unusable.

Answer (score 6):

Try to think like your customer. Would they like to receive the push notifications of the other apps (whatsapp, twitter, the notification that a very important email just arrived)? Of course they would. Your App is one of many and most probably not the most important one they own.

Comment: my query is similar to the actual question so thought to check via comment. 
Say I set a location notification with identifier "qwerty1" and some other app uses same identifier. If I remove my notification then will that remove other app notification as well??

Comment: Of course not. That would be a big security problem.

Comment: Makes sense, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let me provide some background first.

Your app can only receive notifications from your service/server.

The user might have apps that are receiving notifications from the respective service/server. 
e.g. if the user has FB app, then it would be receiving notification from FB servers.

In the end, you are only responsible for managing your service/server.

There is no way for you to block notifications that are received from other services from your app.

Hope this helps.